# Isekai manhwa where a female and male lead swap bodies with one another

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I’m looking for an isekai manhwa where the "weak" female lead and the cold male lead (if I’m not mistaken, they are married) swap bodies with one another all of a sudden.

Comment: This is incredibly brief and body swapping is quite a common trope, can you remember anything else about it at all? What makes this an isekai? Why/how did they swap bodies? Do they eventually swap back? Can you remember anything at all about the plot? When did you read this? Please [edit] this to include anything else you remember, remember the more you include the more likely it is someone will find this for you.

Comment: There's a point I practically have the impression those 2-liners asian ID questions are generated by bots. I mean, lately, these questions practically follow a pattern of always being 2 lined and short and about asian works.

Comment: I'm also not certain if [Isekai] is being used because it's a hot keyword or because people legitimately think it means "fantasy" or "can see stats"...

Answer (score 1):

There are *a lot* of body swap manga/manhwa, but relatively few where the people switching souls are a married couple. Of the ones I checked out, the best match is *[Lady Beast](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/lady-beast)*.

[image]

- It is listed as a manhwa, rather than a manga.
- Shortly after their wedding, the protagonists (a duke and princess) wake up to find that they've somehow switched bodies.
- The duke is portrayed as a somewhat emotionally-detached character, due to a difficult upbringing (he was the product of an extramarital affair), so he could be considered "cold".
- The princess is portrayed as being very soft-spoken and ladylike, so she could be considered "weak".

There isn't an isekai aspect to this story, but then you didn't explain how that applied to the story you have in mind.

Synopsis:

> An arranged marriage that ends in a body swap?! The quiet Princess Elissa has lived a miserable life thus far. To get away from it all she agrees to marry the war tyrant, Duke Ginger of Landall Kingdom. But by some evil curse, the new couple wakes up in each other's bodies! Between royal functions to attend and getting used to their physical changes, can they keep their cool long enough to find a way to switch back? Or will they be stuck like this forever?!

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark beneath the voting buttons.